# Existence of Absolute time

Tags: dhammas

Absolute, true and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own nature flows equably without regard to anything external, and by another name is called duration: relative, apparent and common time, is some sensible and external (whether accurate or unequable) measure of duration by the means of motion, which is commonly used instead of true time ...

According to Newton, absolute time exists independently of any perceiver and progresses at a consistent pace throughout the universe. Unlike relative time, Newton believed absolute time was imperceptible and could only be understood mathematically. According to Newton, humans are only capable of perceiving relative time, which is a measurement of perceivable objects in motion (like the Moon or Sun). From these movements, we infer the passage of time.

After analyze above text by Isaac Newton and state; The "Absolute time" is just a concept rooted from "Anatta"(impermanence) the one of three characteristic of nature in Buddhist teaching. Anatta is everlasting process without end or start and is very helpful to eliminate the wrong view of "creation". So this is one vital explanation that Buddhism ahead of scientific theories. So if I say the fabricated absolute time concept not genuine and the declaration of "Anatta" is the fact and genuine invention,is it acceptable?

Comment: there is no time - time is illusion, so  there is no movement. what is time? time must compose of past-present-future. but apart from the present, the past and future are our mind-concept - doesn't exist in reality. ...its' too deep for general to understand.

Comment: I think most of this question is off-topic (Newtonian Physics), and to the extent that it is on-topic (i.e. about Buddhism) it's perhaps a duplicate, i.e. there's already a general topic about Time and Buddhism.

Comment: Clocks are constantly calibrated and are not 100% certain because of thngs like the superposition of quantum particles in what is used to measure time, classical mechanics do no apply at those scales. There is variation in what is used to measure time, planets and even pulsars are not 100% stable and predictable, anything that has entropy is not absolute reality.